# @salesforce/core ConfigAggregator resolving config file from VSCode root folder

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I'm writing a simple VSCode extension to interact with Salesforce Orgs and I want to leverage @salesforce/core v3 features.

From what I read from ConfigAggregator [documentation](https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-core/classes/configaggregator.html):

> Aggregate global and local project config files, as well as environment variables for sfdx-config.json. The resolution happens in the following bottom-up order:
>
> 1. Environment variables (SFDX_LOG_LEVEL)
> 2. Workspace settings (/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json)
> 3. Global settings ($HOME/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json)

The problem is that no matter what I try, ConfigAggregator never returns local project configs.

I have checked the github repo and found [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/blob/v3/src/util/internal.ts) that the file resolving path starts from the root directory where the node process is created and up:

`export function resolveProjectPathSync(dir: string = process.cwd()): string {`

but `process.cwd()` always return `/appdata/local/Microsoft VS Code` and it never resolves the local config file, which is in the workspace root.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Can you add some more code that is MVC (Minimum Viable Code) that one can repro easily with a Node.js project?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava sure, there's even an example provided on the repo itself [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/tree/v3/examples/examples/displayDefaults), I tried it but still I can't get it to recognize any local config file.
In any ts-node project add @salesforce/core v3 dependency to package.json `"@salesforce/core": "^3.19.0"` then in the main .ts call printConfigs() 
`async function printConfigs(){
 const aggregator = await ConfigAggregator.create();
 console.log(JSON.stringify(aggregator.getConfigInfo()));
}`
All I get is "location":"Global" in the result

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez, no, during development I got stuck with other v3 problems (which I don't recall exactly) so I resorted to switching back to v2 api where this issue is not present